# How can I prove that any group of points created after just one point existing must exist in the same place?

Tags: logic, paradox

How can I prove that any other group of points created after just one point existing (and not in the same place as the original one point that first exists) must exist in the same place (that place being next to the first point)?

This is assuming you're viewing reality from the perspective of being aware of just one point being in existence.

Comment: Is this a way to get at [The Problem of the Many](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/problem-of-many/)? (Also called "the problem of the one and the many".)

Comment: No, see my comment to Rex Kerr's post for what the motivation for this question is.

Comment: This looks like you have found a metaphor you want to use to prove a personal philosophy, but you have not expanded the question enough to admit a non-subjective answer.  For example, in a formal system which includes the axiom "any other group of points created after just one point existing (and not in the same place as the original one point that first exists) must exist in the same place (that place being next to the first point)" trivially admits your proof.

Answer (score 4):

No no no no no.

No.

Points and places do not work that way.

An element of a set X is considered a point when one defines a [topological space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) over that set.  The point is not itself created any more than sets themselves are created - what happens rather is that one brings to the table an additional series of subdivisions of the totality of elements we're interested in to serve as a Topology, and it is in virtue of the subdivisions we accept that we consider something a point.

Is it possible to define a topological space that might totally trivialize all the points and collapse any kind of distinction there?  Of course it is - the topology can simply consist of the full set X and the empty set as the only partitions it admits.  But this isn't an act of creating new points - rather it's just a conscious choice to filter out any other more fine-grained forms of individuated sets that might form a more interesting or complicated basis for our topology.

What you seem to be doing is asserting without proof or clarification that one is confined to viewing all forms of topology within the confines of a two-dimensional and discrete case.  But mathematicians have a logical technology that lets them work around the difficulties of standard first order theory with reference to [Neighbourhoods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)).  The language of Set theory allows us to identify and characterise subspaces, within which individual points can be quantified over as part of the open sets that make up the topology over our space.  Since these subspaces can be individuated in set theory and reasoned about, the functions we appeal to can act without fixing on particular points that we want to position in exact places without thereby giving up on the idea that the topology is itself composed of individual points.

So with a language of continuous functions over topological spaces, there is indeed a way to describe spaces using our discretely based language that do not collapse into point singletons; moreover it's an immensely rich language that gives us access to such a diversity of ways of explaining the spaces we find ourselves in and the surfaces we find ourselves on.

The key is not assuming that the only two things that matter are everything and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You need more constraints for this to be a meaningful exercise.  Let's just take it abstractly: here is a universe with one point: `{foo}`.  Here is a universe with two points: `{foo, bar}`.  Do `foo` and `bar` have anything at all to do with each other in any way?  Maybe not.  Maybe they're effectively in separate existences but we're aware of both.  What does "next to" even mean when you just have a `foo` and `bar`?

So to get started you need to define some sort of distance metric to make "next to" even make sense, and say something else about the properties of these points to justify why you care what "next to" means.

For instance, in the space of mathematical physical laws, if you have only `f = -G*m*M/r^2`, and you add `E = m*c^2`, it hardly seems meaningful to even consider proximity between these two equations.

Comment: [Getsuga Tenshou](http://life.is-best.net/life.pdf). Ctrl+F "because there is nothing to reference the direction
and distance from" the paragraph that ends with that quote is what I'm trying to prove. Feel free to ignore me at this point, I'm being driven crazy.

Comment: @Paul - As I explained above, you don't _even_ have a concept of "next to" or "place".  Arbitrarily deciding that "I don't know what place means" is equivalent to "they are in the same place" is, well, arbitrary.  You can't prove it; place doesn't have any _meaning_ in your hypothetical one-point universe, and it's your job to define it when there is more than one point.